# Why does the first Kafka Producer request to publish take longer than subsequent requests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have a simple kafka producer where I have enabled retries by giving `retries` as 3.
I need to set an interval between retries and I have set the same using
`retry.backoff.ms`. However, I am able to see that the initial request to publish takes as much time as is specified in the `retry.backoff.ms` config. If the `retry.backoff.ms` is 100 I get the response after publishing in around 110 ms and if I give `retry.backoff.ms` as 60000 ms  (1 min, after increasing the `max.block.ms accordingly`)the first request takes slightly more than 60000 ms. Why am I observing this behavior? Does spring kafka do a dummy retry on initial connection?
I'm on java 8, spring boot 1.5.9 with Edgware.SR1 cloud version.

Comment: Can you check the kafka server.log, if there's any relevant info there?

Comment: you mean both properties are set to 60000 @user